# How to achieve lower latency with android videoview for live video by lowering buffer?

Tags: java, android, stream, raspberry-pi, android-videoview

I'm working on an app that receives a live video from my raspberry pi. So far, it works experimentally but has a huge latency of about 10-13 seconds. It is critical for my application to achieve near instant (no more than 1.5 second delay) from my pi. 
I have achieved a 2 second latency when I was viewing on my pc using vlc (tcp/rtp streaming) after tweaking vlc settings to reduce buffer size and use sockets to record the video, so I know that the problem is not on the pi's end.
To stream the video, I am using cvlc and raspivid:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -vf -w 320 -h 180 -fps 24 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8000}' :demux=h264
```

On my app's end, I am able to play video but with large latency with the following code:

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    String path ="http://"+IPaddress+':'+VPort;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
```

How can I decrease my latency to an acceptable value?